# Is Magic Keyboard for iPad Air 4th Gen compatible with Air 5th Gen

Tags: keyboard, ipad, magic-keyboard-ipad

I have an iPad Air 5th Gen, and I found a good deal for an older Magic Keyboard (model A2261) which says it's compatible with Air 4th Gen. Would the same keyboard work with the latest Air model?

This is the model info from the packaging:
[image]

[image]